# How I can distibute values over the computational cells?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fluid-dynamics, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I am an engineering student and I try to solve the fluid equations over a given set of computational cells. I have a mathematical question about a field I am currently studying, precisely the following one:

[image: Computational fields]

We know that the properties can be distributed over the cells using a diffusion equation.
But here, I need to distribute the values from the known cells to the solid ones. The criteria will be the zero gradient distribution over the arrows. Can anyone help me to figure out what kind of mathematical operation should I use in order to fulfill my task? What is the diffusion equation I have to apply in this situation?

Comment: [Cross posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375903/how-i-can-distibute-values-over-the-computational-cells).